# If $f(x)=e^x -mx$ where $m>0$, and $f(x)=0$ has one solution, find that solution and the exact value of m.

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=e^x -mx$ where $m>0$, and $f(x)=0$ has one solution, find that solution and the exact value of m.

Hello, I am unsure how you would find an exact value of m in this case, and also what the given information is trying to tell me, could somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: Sorry, as you can see, I am a new contributor. I was under the impression that it being involved with solutions had something to do with it. As you can see, I am unsure how to solve this question and hence am unaware whether it actually uses linear algebra or not. In future, maybe instead of asking me, explaining where it would be better suited would be a better use of time.

Comment: What about $m = e^x/x$ ?

Comment: You are looking for the tangent line to $y=e^x$, that passes through the origin.

Comment: This tangent line is $y=e.x$, so $m=e$.

Comment: @Cactus Will that be sufficient as a response? I got that as an answer but I think it's too obvious, I'm not sure. and Kmitov, could you explain your process for m=e?

Comment: Seeing the comments of @kmitov, I assume that your problem is "for which $m$ does $f_m(x) = 0$ have only one solution", right ? Next time, try to be clearer please. If it is indeed this, try to study the function $f_m$. You should be able to show that it decreases on $]-\infty,\ln(m)]$ and it increases on $[\ln(m),+\infty[$. And $f(-\infty) = f(+\infty) = +\infty$, thus $f(x) = 0$ has exactly one solution if and only if $f(\ln(m)) = 0$, which means $m = e$.

Comment: @Cactus I was as clear as possible, my question is exactly phrased how I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Plot the graph of $$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x}$$
Let's just consider the part above $x$ axis as $m>0$. [image]

You can see that it will have two solutions for every value of $m$ except the value that is at the minima. So the line should be tangent to $f(x)$.
$$\boxed{\implies m=e}$$